# Change the style of an array of String inside a TextView - swift - EDIT

Tags: swift, textview

My first question was how to change the Font of a word example "test" in a textView, and it was answered correctly by @bkrl and @Torongo.

```
func changeAllOccurence(of string: String, font: UIFont) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    var range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.mutableString.length)

    while(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: string, options: .caseInsensitive, range: range)
        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                                          value: font,
                                          range: range)
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, self.characters.count - (range.location + range.length));
        }
    }

    return attributedString
}
```

As I am still not familiar with the above code, I tried to add few lines in order to generalize the code so it can works for an array of strings and not only one string.
But for sure it didn't works cause it changed the font of the last word only which is reasonable cause the final changes will be for the last word which is "usage":

```
        let words = ["example", "usage"]
        for word in words {
        let attributedText = text.changeAllOccurence(of: word, font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17))
        textview.attributedText = attributedText
    }
```

Can someone advise how to improve the code provided by @Toromgo in order to work for any array of strings instead of just one?

Comment: Sorry but you must use [AttributedStrings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have changed your question, ihave updated my answer accordingly. Please try this:

```
extension String {

    func changeAllOccurence(of strings: [String], font: UIFont) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        for eachString in strings {
            var range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.mutableString.length)

            while(range.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                range = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: eachString, options: .caseInsensitive, range: range)
                if(range.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                                                  value: font,
                                                  range: range)
                    range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, self.characters.count - (range.location + range.length));
                }
            }
        }
        return attributedString
    }

}
```

I have run the code and it is working.

Comment: If I will search for a word "example", textview will be empty. If i put nothing "" in String, text will be visible. Can you please try it?

Comment: Great, it work fine for one string. I tried to do this for an array of [string] instead of one string, for example to make bold each string in [example, test, maybe] but it was little hard. can we generalize this code to work for a array of string?

Answer (score 3):

You could create extension like:

```
extension String {

    func change(font: UIFont, of string: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        let subStringRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: string,
                                                                  options: .caseInsensitive)
        if subStringRange.location != NSNotFound {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                                          value: font,
                                          range: subStringRange)
        }
        return attributedString
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let text = "This is example of usage extension"
let attributedText = text.change(font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17), of: "example")
textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you, but the question is about font, not about the font color . You just need to chane the NSAttribute to font and change it to bold :) Anyway nice solution

Comment: @DominikBucher You're right, answer updated. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: The code above will detect only the very first word "example", so if I have 10 similar words "example", only the very first word will be bold.